# footer css query

Tags: html, css

**Here is some HTML code:**

```
<div id="footer-widgets" class="grid-container clearfix">
    <div class="footer-box grid-3">
        <div class="footer-widget wpex-social-widget clearfix"><h4>UNITE WITH US :</h4><ul class="wpex-clearfix"><li class="wpex-social-twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/mockinvest" title="twitter"><img src="http://www.invadewallst.com/wp-content/themes/invadewallst/images/social/twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></a></li><li class="wpex-social-facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/iMock-Invest/368514516550764?ref=hl" title="facebook"><img src="http://www.invadewallst.com/wp-content/themes/invadewallst/images/social/facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></a></li><li class="wpex-social-youtube"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/imockinvest" title="youtube"><img src="http://www.invadewallst.com/wp-content/themes/invadewallst/images/social/youtube.png" alt="YouTube"></a></li></ul></div>            </div>
    <!-- /footer-left -->
    </div>
    <!-- /footer-middle -->
    <div class="footer-box grid-3">
    </div>
    <!-- /footer-right -->
    <div class="footer-box grid-3">
    </div>
    <!-- /footer-right -->
</div>

<br/>
```

**Please tell me what to change CSS..**

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Without posting any code in your OP, this question becomes useless to others, in the future, after you fix your site.

Comment: Hey, I kepted some code above... pls kindly telll me now atleast...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong header, use `h4` instead `h3`